# NSMutableArray within singleton class always returns count 0 / never retains its objects

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, singleton, nsmutablearray

My simplified singleton looks like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray * myArray;
}

+ (MyClass*) instance;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

Then in the implementation

```
static MyClass * myinstance;
@synthesize myArray;

+ (MyClass*) instance {
    if(myinstance == nil)
        myinstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];

    return myinstance;
}


- (id) init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
      myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
      [myArray addObject:@"Trauma"];
     }
     return self;
}
```

However when I try to access it for a tableview this always returns 0:

```
[[[MyClass instance] myArray] count];
```

Little unsure about what I'm doing wrong

Comment: This code looks like it would work. I would suggest the actual code in your app has a bug in it. So what might you be doing that is different from what you posted here?

Answer (score 2):

The method that returns the instance of your singleton is named `+instance`, but when attempting to access your singleton, you are using `+myinstance`. Your instance of `MyClass` is most likely nil.

Comment: I'm surprised that the code in the question isn't giving a compiler error.

Comment: It must be generating at least a warning, but who knows how big that list of warnings is ;)

Comment: Actually thats a typo: I had translated my code with names to more general code. Editing now... (Also I have 0 warnings with the compiler :p)

Comment: So you would like help finding a bug in your actual code by having people read this code that isn't in fact your actual code? :)

Comment: Try changing myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2]; to myArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2] retain];